# D3js maximum call stack exceeded with zoom.js function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been experimenting with D3js and ran into a "max call stack exceeded" message while trying to implement multi-zoom behaviour through programmatically invoking the zoomEvent. I have made a simple jsFiddle program to demonstrate the problem. Below is a minimal reproducible code.

```
const svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.attr("class", "rootSvg").attr("width", 300).attr("height", 300);

const redRect = svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("height", 300)
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("fill", "red");

const blueRect = svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("height", 300)
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("fill", "blue")
  .attr("x", 150);

const redRectZoomBH = d3.zoom();
const blueRectZoomBH = d3.zoom();

const zoomRedRect = ({ sourceEvent }) => {
  if (sourceEvent === null) return; //<-------- This check doesnt work??
  console.log("zooming red with red zoom function");
  redRect.call(redRectZoomBH.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
};

const zoomBlueRect = ({ sourceEvent }) => {
  if (sourceEvent === null) return;
  console.log("zooming red with blue zoom function");
  redRect.call(redRectZoomBH.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
};

redRect.call(redRectZoomBH.on("zoom", zoomRedRect));
blueRect.call(blueRectZoomBH.on("zoom", zoomBlueRect));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SkySoft2/5ywzuaq2/3/

The program shows a red and blue rectangle. Zooming in blue will programmatically call red's zoomEvent and zooming the red rectangle will call red's zoomEvent. In red and blue's zoom function there is a check if the sourceEvent is valid or not before calling triggering a zoomEvent.

The problem is triggering red's zoomEvent while zooming blue rectangle, the sourceEvent is null and there will not be an infinite loop. But zooming red and triggering red's zoomEvent will cause an infinite loop because sourceEvent is not null and instead is a legit wheelEvent.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and is there a way to check if the zoomEvent is programmatically triggered or triggered by legit wheelEvent

Comment: To help with an answer and for clarity, why do you need to call the red zoom function from the red zoom function? Normally you'd just call the zoom function once per zoom - why finish by calling the zoom function again? I can't see a case where a zoom would need to be immediately followed up by another zoom - I believe I have an answer for that, but think I could make it more useful if I knew a bit more. If you can share any details on the relationship between red and blue zooms as well, it could make for a more relevant answer.

Comment: Hi, my application creates a graph and uses mouseArea (rect) on left/right yAxis to allow zooming in the yAxis. inorder to sync their zoom transformation, I used another invisible mouseArea to store the actual transformation. When either the left/right gets zoomed, I trigger the invs mouseArea's zoomEvent and that in turn will programmatically trigger the zoomEvents of the left/right mouseArea to sync all zoom transformations. The bug I described only happens when I zoom rapidly between the left and right. Hope you can understand